# Groupbox - change border colour - RowPosition error

Tags: vb.net, groupbox

I have this code to change border colour of Groupboxes. It adds custom groupbox to my Toolbox and I can change border colour, but every time I start debugging I get this error: ***InvalidArgument=Value of "-2147483648" is not valid for 'RowPosition'.***. As I read online, this error is produced when there is some bad code in project. Anybody knows how I should deal with this ?

```
Public Class GroupBox_Color
    Inherits GroupBox

    Private _borderColor As Color

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me._borderColor = Color.Blue
    End Sub

    Public Property BorderColor() As Color
        Get
            Return Me._borderColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            Me._borderColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim tSize As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Me.Text, Me.Font)
        Dim borderRect As Rectangle = Me.DisplayRectangle

        borderRect.Y = (borderRect.Y + (tSize.Height / 2))
        borderRect.Height = (borderRect.Height - (tSize.Height / 2))

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRect, Me._borderColor,
                            ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

        Dim textRect As Rectangle = Me.DisplayRectangle
        textRect.X = (textRect.X + 6)
        textRect.Width = tSize.Width
        textRect.Height = tSize.Height

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor), textRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor), textRect)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: turn on Option Strict.  Are you purposely drawing the frame much much smaller than the client rect for a reason?

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for this, now It works. No, this was just something I found on sites, I allready changed frame size to normal. Do you, by any chance, know of any oval shape that I could download to my toolbox and use same way to make this custom border with rounded edges, as regular groupbox has ?

Comment: It is not hard to *draw* a rounded rectangle.  If that is what you want the control to do, you dont need another control - just paint this one differently.  I later found where this came from; it should be using TextRender rather than DrawString and it is not disposing of that brush.  I didnt post an answer because the Q is not really about the groupbox

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks, I'll look for this rounded rectangle solution.